# Different text i18n in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, internationalization

In my rails application I have a partial(`file1/_partial.html.erb`) that must be rendered in Two form  `file2/form1.html.erb` and `file3/_partial.html.erb`, I'am wondering what is the best solution to i18n a text in the partial

actually what I'm doing is

```
<%= (t :to_ranslate, :scope => 'file2.form1' ) %>

  file2:
    form1:
      to_ranslate: "translated"
```

and this is working but I'm wondering if there is a solution where can I have different translation based on template so for the same partial i will have different text based on where it is rendered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not need different translations when included in different templates you can just use the "Lazy Lookup" as described here in 4.1.4: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#looking-up-translations

It also applies to rendering partials, for example:

```
in file1/_partial.html.erb
<%= (t '.to_translate') %>

in the translations.yml:
en:
  file1:
    _partial:
      to_translate: "translated"
```

For using different translations depending on where you render from, like so (untested but the principle should work):

```
in file1/_partial.html.erb
<%= (t "#{translation_scope.to_s}.to_translate') %>

in file2/form1.html.erb
<%= render '/file1/partial', translation_scope: 'file2._partial' %>

in file3/_partial.html.erb
<%= render '/file1/partial', translation_scope: 'file3._partial' %>

in the translations.yml
en:
  file1:
    _partial:
      to_translate: "translated"
  file2:
    _partial:
      to_translate: "translated"
  file2:
    _partial:
      to_translate: "translated"
```

This would have the advantage that it still works when you do not specify the translation_scope (falling back to its default) and also when you pass it.
This is the reason why i would prefer it over using the scope: 'xx' like you did.
And the whole interface seems a little bit like inheritance in the views with the same structure everywhere.

In a more abstract and complicated way it would also be possible to use fallbacks for this, but in the example here this would be overkill. On larger projects it might make sense to implement something like this.

Comment: And if I need different translation for the same partial based in where it is rendered

Comment: In this case i would pass in a scope when rendering the partial, ill update my answer in a moment

Comment: I don't understand why I must render partial form in partial form

Answer (score 0):

as far as i know rails is internationalized by default out of the box
just place the text as you would normally and it should work no problem.

reference: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html